# Preferred method for disputing an edit

Tags: discussion, support, edits

Not long ago I made an edit correcting many minor grammatical errors that was soon accepted.

I'm by no means under the impression that my revision is perfect, but it was soon re-edited with minor changes that weren't necessarily incorrect in my revision.

I was wondering what the proper method to handle a dispute would be, as I don't mean to assume incorrectly that I'm just meant to re-edit.

This is the revision in question, in case anyone can point out if there are specific reasons as to why those changes needed to be made - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15546466/revisions

Comment: I'm not really sure why he thought that edit needed to be made, but I wouldn't worry about it. It doesn't cause harm to the post so just let it be.

Comment: In this case, the edit was correct. Generally, dont take edits personally

Comment: I read all the edits you've made. They look perfect except for one minor thing. Feel free to remove "Please help" from questions.

Comment: Not only that edit was minor. There's another edit suggestion on the question, which is even more minor IMO (or less major), which received a Reject from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The site is collaboratively edited, and edits can also be rolled back again. I see little need to 'dispute' this additional edit.

Your edit, however, does like like a change from a variable name (`earthCircumfence`) to a proper noun ("Earth's Circumfence"), and the second editor felt that needed to be changed. The second change probably was merely meant to meet minimum edit requirements.

If you do get into a dispute over edits (where you end up in an edit war), step back, and at best flag the post for a moderator to take a look at the situation. Choose 'other' and explain. This is not such a situation, however.

Comment: That is exactly what I sought to avoid.